# Why does this code throw an access violation exception?

Tags: c++, sfml

Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML/Window.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <SFML/Text.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Game
{
    private:

        bool kratka[9];
        bool tak;

        sf::RenderWindow okno;

        sf::Image ikolo;
        sf::Image ikrzyz;

        sf::Texture tkolo;
        sf::Texture tkrzyz;

        sf::Sprite kolo[9];
        sf::Sprite krzyz[9];

        sf::Sprite minkz;
        sf::Sprite minko;

        sf::Vector2f vec;
        sf::Vector2i mouse;

        sf::Font font;

        sf::Text Gracz1;
        sf::Text Gracz2;

        sf::Text wynik1;
        sf::Text wynik2;

        sf::Texture tkrata;
        sf::Texture spowtorz;

        sf::Sprite powtorz;
        sf::Sprite skrata[9];
        int ikr[9];   // zmienne odpowiadajace za logiczna wartosc kraty
        int rzad[8]; //kombinacje rzedow

        int player1;
        int player2;

        string sp1;
        string sp2;

        void update_licznik();

        static const int krata=150;

        void process();
        void update();
        void render();

        bool jestna(sf::Sprite &sp);
        bool gracz;

    public:
        Game();
        void run();
};

Game::Game():okno(sf::VideoMode(800,600,32),"Kolko i krzyzyk")
{
    tkrata.loadFromFile("sprites/kratka.png");
    ikolo.loadFromFile("sprites/kolo.png");
    ikrzyz.loadFromFile("sprites/krzyz.png");
    spowtorz.loadFromFile("sprites/powtorz.png");
    ikrzyz.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color(255,255,255),0);
    ikolo.createMaskFromColor(sf::Color(255,255,255),0);

    okno.setFramerateLimit(30);

    tkolo.loadFromImage(ikolo);
    tkrzyz.loadFromImage(ikrzyz);

    minkz.setTexture(tkrzyz);
    minkz.setPosition(670,270);
    minkz.setScale(0.7,0.7);

    minko.setTexture(tkolo);
    minko.setPosition(0,270);
    minko.setScale(0.7,0.7);

    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            kolo[3*i+j].setTexture(tkolo);
            krzyz[3*i+j].setTexture(tkrzyz);
            kolo[3*i+j].setPosition(i*150+175,j*150+75);
            krzyz[3*i+j].setPosition(i*150+175,j*150+75);
        }
    }

    font.loadFromFile("sprites/poseiAOE.ttf");
    Gracz1.setFont(font);
    Gracz1.setString("Gracz 1");
    Gracz1.setCharacterSize(70);

    Gracz2.setFont(font);
    Gracz2.setString("Gracz 2");
    Gracz2.setCharacterSize(70);
    Gracz2.setPosition(650,0);

    wynik1.setFont(font);
    wynik2.setFont(font);
    wynik1.setCharacterSize(300);
    wynik2.setCharacterSize(300);
    wynik1.setPosition(25,0);
    wynik2.setPosition(700,0);

    powtorz.setTexture(spowtorz);
    powtorz.setPosition(640,440);

    player2=0;
    player2=0;

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        ikr[i]=0;
        rzad[i]=0;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
        {
            skrata[3*i+j].setTexture(tkrata);
            skrata[3*i+j].setPosition(i*150+175,j*150+75);
        }
    }


}

void Game::update_licznik()
{
    sp1=to_string(player1);
    sp2=to_string(player2);
    wynik1.setString(sp1);
    wynik2.setString(sp2);
}


bool Game::jestna(sf::Sprite &sp)
{
    vec=sp.getPosition();
    mouse=sf::Mouse::getPosition(okno);

    if(mouse.x>vec.x && mouse.x<vec.x+krata && mouse.y>vec.y && mouse.y<vec.y+krata)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

void Game::process()
{
    sf::Event zdarzenie;
    while(okno.pollEvent(zdarzenie))
    {
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {
            if(zdarzenie.type==sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && jestna(skrata[i]) && ikr[i]==0)
            {
                gracz=!gracz;
                if(gracz)
                    ikr[i]++;
                else
                    ikr[i]--;
            }   
            if(zdarzenie.type==sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && jestna(powtorz))
            {
                for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                {
                    ikr[i]=0;
                }
            }
        }

        if(zdarzenie.type==sf::Event::Closed)
            okno.close();
    }
}

void Game::update()
{
    update_licznik();
    rzad[0]=ikr[0]+ikr[1]+ikr[2];
    rzad[1]=ikr[0]+ikr[3]+ikr[6];
    rzad[2]=ikr[2]+ikr[5]+ikr[8];
    rzad[3]=ikr[6]+ikr[7]+ikr[8];
    rzad[4]=ikr[3]+ikr[4]+ikr[5];
    rzad[5]=ikr[1]+ikr[4]+ikr[7];
    rzad[6]=ikr[0]+ikr[4]+ikr[8];
    rzad[7]=ikr[2]+ikr[4]+ikr[6];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        if(rzad[i]==3)
        {
            player1++;
            rzad[i]=0;
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                ikr[i]=0;

        }
        if(rzad[i]==-3)
        {
            player2++;
            rzad[i]=0;
            for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
                ikr[i]=0;
        }
    }
}

void Game::render()
{
    okno.clear();
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
    {
        okno.draw(skrata[i]);
        if(ikr[i]==1)
            okno.draw(kolo[i]);
        if(ikr[i]==-1)
            okno.draw(krzyz[i]);
    }
    okno.draw(Gracz1);
    okno.draw(Gracz2);
    okno.draw(wynik1);
    okno.draw(wynik2);
    okno.draw(powtorz);
    okno.draw(minkz);
    okno.draw(minko);
    okno.display();
}

void Game::run()
{
    while(okno.isOpen())
    {
        process();
        update();
        render();
    }
}

int main()
{
    Game game;
    game.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run this code, I get the following exception:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x505D4361 (msvcr110d.dll) in Gra1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCCCCCCCC
```

Comment: You should reduce your code to get a [sscce](http://sscce.org/). It helps to spot where you're crashing. Also, a debugger will help **A LOT**.

Comment: In `Game` constructor `rzad[i]=0;` will be an overflow in last iteration due to `rzad[8]`. Also, you initialize `player2` twice, you omitted `player1`.

Answer (score -2):

Where it crashes is mostly something, you should be figuring out with a debugger, but looking at the code, there are a lot of mistakes.

The code above shouldn't even compile, due to the fact that `SFML/Text.hpp` is not a valid header.

`using namespace std;` is mostly a bad thing and if its done at global scope, it's just plain wrong to do so. Namespaces are there to a) prevent name clashes and b) make it obvious where a class is originating from, thus in most cases you shouldn't be `using` namespaces.

Every variables needs to be initialized. If it's a class with a default constructor, you won't have to do anything, but if its an `int` or an `bool` you have to initialize it, otherwise you'll be running an application with undefined behavior, which means it could blow up anytime. Since you're using classes, you should be initializing the variables in the constructor's initialization list, like you did with the window.

As ch0kee pointed out in the comments, `rzad` will run into an overflow. Unfortunately an application might still keep running, due to the fact that accessing the element after the last one in an array is guaranteed to be a valid pointer and if you assign 0 to it, you might get lucky in some cases. Even though the "pointer" will be valid you should not write to or read from its underlying content. You can prevent such issues, by using `std::vector` or with C++11 `std::array`, which couples the data with its size, thus allowing for accurate and more error free bounds checking.

In `proccess()` and `update()` you're using `for` loops to iterate over the arrays, but you're using multiple times the index variable `i`, thus overshadowing the other index. You should always using different indices for nested loops, not only to make it possible to use indices from higher up, but also to reduce confusion.

As a final word, you might want to write the variable names in English. It's okay to use your native language for programming, but as soon as you ask for help of someone not native in that language, the other person will have problems understanding the meaning of your application.

If you fix all said above it shouldn't crash anymore. By the way activating a higher level of error checking at compile time is a valuable thing, since it will already tell you a lot of your mistakes through warnings.

Comment: You're right with the using namespace information, but in this case, it seems it's just one big mama cpp file, so for testing sake, it's easier to use the namespace, less typing. But you're right, NEVER put `using` statement inside a header file.